# Unable to find installed emulators in Eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have downloaded the add-ons for Sony Xperia, Motorola XOOM, Galaxy Tab, Kindle Fire etc., I can see all those add-ons in `android-sdk-macos\add-ons` folder. But, when I am trying to create the AVD/emulator for Sony Xperia, Galaxy Tab etc., I couldn't find those items in the list.

Here is the screen shot for the add-on folder in `android-sdk-macosx` folder
[image]

Here is the screen shot for the AVD manager of Eclipse

[image]

In the above list, I couldn't see Sony Xperia Tablet, Motorola XOOM Samsung Galaxy Tab etc., Could you tell me why?

I am creating an app for tablets. I want to make my application to work on all the tablets. I dont have all the devices. How to create different emulators for different kinds of devices. 
Please donot make this question as duplicate. I have seen many question in `stackoverflow`. I dint find any solution.

I want my application to work on
`Acer Iconia Tab A701`,
`ASUS Transformer Pad Infinity 700`,
`Sony Xperia Tablet S`,
`Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10 inches`,

Comment: i also want to add different platform emulators in eclipse. can you please provide me the add ons URL for the different platforms.

Comment: @NareshSharma.. May I know what are the different platforms you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those add-ons will appear in the Targets list when creating a new AVD, provided that you have the correct API versions installed.  You'll only be able to use their software configurations, though, and the graphical skins will not be automatically applied.

Device definitions are a new feature in version 21 of the ADT, and none of those add-ons are new enough to have added their own device definition.  You can make your own definitions to match the hardware configurations of the add-on devices, but unfortunately you won't be able to just select it from a list and have the emulator configured completely to match the device like you could in previous versions of the ADT.

So when creating a new AVD, the Device list is for device definitions, and the Target list is for add-ons or software configurations.  You'll need both to make a new AVD.

[image]

This is all based on my personal experience, as the docs had not been updated for this new revision when I last checked, so I apologize if this is incorrect.